# Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: craft3, array

Here we go:

```
{% set state = craft.categories.group('locations').level(1).title(entry.title).one() %}
{% set solution = craft.categories.group('institutionSolutions').title(entry.parent.title).one() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('institutions').relatedTo('and', state, solution).limit(4) %}

   {% for entry in entries %}
       {{ entry.title }}
   {% endfor %}
```

The following code does work as expected in Craft 2. According to the docs in Craft 3 we have to use the array brackets. So this

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('institutions').relatedTo('and', state, solution).limit(4) %}
```

will become to this

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('institutions').relatedTo(['and', state, solution).limit(4) %}
```

as a result I see the following message:

array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: You're missing a closing square bracket fyi...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are going to apply an `and` in your `relatedTo` in Craft 3 it expects the following arguments to be arrays with the structure like [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/relations.html#passing-multiple-relation-criteria)

```
{% set entries = craft
    .entries
    .section('institutions')
    .relatedTo(['and', 
        {element: state}, // <- or targetElement / sourceElement
        {element: solution}
    ])
    .limit(4) 
    .all()
%}
```

Comment: You saved me with the `{element: variable}` syntax. Where did you learn that from? I can't find syntax like that anywhere in the docs.

Comment: @Brimby it's in the documentation I linked in my post